# Xpath with scrapy shell

Tags: xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape startup articles on this page https://techmoran.com/category/startups/ usin scrapy shell using the following xpath command:

```
>>> n=response.xpath('//article[contains(@class, "jeg_post jeg_pl_md_box")]/div/div/a/@href').getall()

>>> len(n)
30
```

The command is only returning 30 articles instead of 2880 which I can see when I try the
//article[contains(@class, "jeg_post jeg_pl_md_box")]/div/div/a/@href'
on the inspector in Chrome. How do I get the rest of the articles?

Comment: Add a sample of the html containing those tags please. How do you know there are 2880 articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an infinite scroll, every page has 30 articles.

Find the url and the request:

[image]

```
scrapy shell
In [1]: url = 'https://techmoran.com/?ajax-request=jnews'

In [2]: page = 1

In [3]: data = {
    "lang": "en_US",
    "action": "jnews_module_ajax_jnews_block_34",
    "module": "true",
    "data[filter]": "0",
    "data[filter_type]": "all",
    "data[current_page]": f"{page}",
    "data[attribute][header_icon]": "",
    "data[attribute][first_title]": "",
    "data[attribute][second_title]": "",
    "data[attribute][url]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_type]": "heading_6",
    "data[attribute][header_background]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_secondary_background]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_text_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_line_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_accent_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_filter_category]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_filter_author]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_filter_tag]": "",
    "data[attribute][header_filter_text]": "All",
    "data[attribute][post_type]": "post",
    "data[attribute][content_type]": "all",
    "data[attribute][number_post]": "30",
    "data[attribute][post_offset]": "7",
    "data[attribute][unique_content]": "disable",
    "data[attribute][include_post]": "",
    "data[attribute][exclude_post]": "",
    "data[attribute][include_category]": "5",
    "data[attribute][exclude_category]": "",
    "data[attribute][include_author]": "",
    "data[attribute][include_tag]": "",
    "data[attribute][exclude_tag]": "",
    "data[attribute][gallerycat]": "",
    "data[attribute][sort_by]": "latest",
    "data[attribute][date_format]": "default",
    "data[attribute][date_format_custom]": "Y/m/d",
    "data[attribute][pagination_mode]": "scrollload",
    "data[attribute][pagination_nextprev_showtext]": "",
    "data[attribute][pagination_number_post]": "30",
    "data[attribute][pagination_scroll_limit]": "0",
    "data[attribute][el_id]": "",
    "data[attribute][el_class]": "",
    "data[attribute][scheme]": "",
    "data[attribute][column_width]": "auto",
    "data[attribute][title_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][accent_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][alt_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][excerpt_color]": "",
    "data[attribute][css]": "",
    "data[attribute][excerpt_length]": "20",
    "data[attribute][paged]": "1",
    "data[attribute][pagination_align]": "center",
    "data[attribute][pagination_navtext]": "false",
    "data[attribute][pagination_pageinfo]": "false",
    "data[attribute][boxed]": "false",
    "data[attribute][boxed_shadow]": "false",
    "data[attribute][box_shadow]": "false",
    "data[attribute][push_archive]": "true",
    "data[attribute][ads_type]": "googleads",
    "data[attribute][ads_position]": "5",
    "data[attribute][ads_random]": "false",
    "data[attribute][ads_image]": "",
    "data[attribute][ads_image_link]": "",
    "data[attribute][ads_image_alt]": "",
    "data[attribute][ads_image_new_tab]": "true",
    "data[attribute][google_publisher_id]": "<script+data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-4793005812421081\"+async+src=\"https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>",
    "data[attribute][google_slot_id]": "<script+async+src=\"https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>+<ins+class=\"adsbygoogle\"++++++style=\"display:block\"++++++data-ad-format=\"fluid\"++++++data-ad-layout-key=\"-cs+6-1e-q8+12p\"++++++data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-4793005812421081\"++++++data-ad-slot=\"8266744001\"></ins>+<script>++++++(adsbygoogle+=+window.adsbygoogle+||+[]).push({});+</script>",
    "data[attribute][google_desktop]": "auto",
    "data[attribute][google_tab]": "auto",
    "data[attribute][google_phone]": "auto",
    "data[attribute][code]": "",
    "data[attribute][ads_class]": "inline_module",
    "data[attribute][column_class]": "jeg_col_3o3",
    "data[attribute][class]": "jnews_block_34"
}

In [4]: req = scrapy.FormRequest(url=url, formdata=data)

In [5]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://techmoran.com/?ajax-request=jnews> (referer: None)

######## Here you'll get a json (content = response.json()['content']), scrape your articles from it. #######

In [6]: page += 1
........
........
........
```

Comment: Thank you. Where did you get all that information in data = {...}?

Comment: @nhamster from devtools->Request. Look at the photo.

Comment: I should be missing something because my view of dev tools on both chrome and firefox of the same page looks just like the inspector. I cannot see the view you have in the image. Thanks for all the help provided.

Comment: @nhamster in the devtools click on the "network", and then go to the page (or refresh if you're already there).